# parameterized query using textbox as a filter

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql, datagrid, visual-studio-2015

On a CRM Database I have a form with all the clients details (from PostgreSQL)
and underneath it there is a `datagrid` I need filled with all the data about visit to the client whose details are currently displayed above.
I can't find a way to filter the data in the datagrid according to one of the text boxes in the details view.

I tried to create a parameterized query with:

```
SELECT
WHERE client_code = @client_code
```

but it just gives me
Error in WHERE clause near '@' Unable to parse query text.

also I have no idea how to define the @client_code parameter.

Comment: `select yourColumn from yourTable where...`  Are you trying to filter from the DB or from the DataSource on the grid?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I'm trying to filter from the DB

Comment: I don't have any other relevant code other than
SELECT "v_ID", v_data, v_client, ....... FROM "public"."visits to clients"
WHERE v_client = @client_code
but that doesn't even let me save the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correct you are trying to run the query without defining the parameter `@client_code`. Try:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT <FIELD_NAME1>,<FIELD_NAME2.. FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE client_code = @client_code", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_code", myTExtbox.Text);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {          
      da.Fill(dt);
    }     
    myDatGrid.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapters will open and close the connection for you, so you don't need that `con.Open();` line.

Comment: For some reason my Db tables all changed names from [table] to public.[tablet]. After renaming then back everything works fine. Thanks.